# webdriverio 5.7.5 getting error $(...).setValue is not a function

Tags: typescript, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, webdriver-io, supertest

I am have a working webdriverio framework which executes without any issue. But recently I included a REST api call in between and since then any wdio commands followed the api call is failing with the error message that "is not a function"

The api response is successful. Without api the same wdio methods are executed successfully.

- I tried to compare the browser session before and after webdriverio and they both are same

  - I tried moving the api call to a seperate file. But after the execution of api call, when the next step is called facing the same error message
  - I tried to store and reuse the browser value, but no good.
  - I tried to open a window , run the api call , close the window : But close window is not working at all
  - I tried switch window using the url and title, but did not help at all.

Something happens weird that $ functionality loses the track of wdio instance if there is an api call in between. I am struggling to fix this and without having api call in between , cant create my test automation framework. Hence input on this will be much appreciated.

The sample code I used is given below for your refeence

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import apiCheck from 'src/ext/api.check';
import lPage from 'src/pages/login.page';
import sPage from 'src/pages/summary.page';

let superTest = require('supertest');

const request = superTest('http://localhost:3000/api/');
const apiEndPoint = 'auth/login';
const headerOrigin = 'http://localhost:3001';
const headerCookie = '__DEEI_SESSION__=abcd1234';


describe('fund part ', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            browser.url('login?');
        });


        it('Get API Response in seperate ts file and run through wdio steps', async () => {
            let accountNo = lPage.getLoginAccountType('Standard');

            try {
                    let res = await apiCheck.getApiLoginData(accountNo);
                    console.log(res);

                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }

            lPage.enterLoginData(accountNo, '2dsXS£');
        });

        it('Get API Response in same it block and run through wdio steps', async () => {

            let accountNo = lPage.getLoginAccountType('Standard');

            let requestBody = `{"username": \"${accountNo}\", "password": "2dsXS£$"}`;
            let response = await request
                .post(apiEndPoint)
                .send(requestBody)
                .set('Origin', headerOrigin)
                .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                .set('Cookie', headerCookie)
                .expect(200);


            lPage.enterLoginData(accountNo, password);
            });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of supertest, try using [sync-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request). This would make Rest request synchronous for use in testing environment.

```
const request = require('sync-request');
it('Get API Response in same it block and run through wdio steps', () => {

            let accountNo = lPage.getLoginAccountType('Standard');

            let requestBody = `{"username": \"${accountNo}\", "password": "2dsXS£$"}`;
            let response = request(
                'POST',
                '_SOME_POST_END_POINT',
                {
                    headers: { _SOME_HEADER_IF_NEEDED_},
                    json: {_JSON_FOR_POST}
                }
            );


            lPage.enterLoginData(accountNo, password);
            });
```